# how to scroll to next item by clicking on a checkbox in each item (recyclerview)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, custom-adapter, android-viewholder

Forgive me for my English.

My list contains 100 items. Each item consists of two checkboxes and I want to scroll to the next item each time a checkbox is clicked.

please give me the best answer link If this question has already been answered

this is my custom adapter

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends 
       RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList answerFirst;
private ArrayList answerSecond;
private Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context  context, ArrayList questionList, ArrayList 
answerFirst, ArrayList answerSecond) {
    this.context = context;
    this.answerFirst = answerFirst;
    this.answerSecond = answerSecond;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = 
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_items, 
    parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) 
    {

        holder.firstanswer.setText(answerFirst.get(position).toString());
        holder.secondanswer.setText(answerSecond.get(position).toString());
    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return questionList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView question;
    CheckBox firstanswer;
    CheckBox secondanswer;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        question = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_text);
        firstanswer = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_answer);
        secondanswer = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.second_answer);
             }
        }
   }
```

this is the main activity

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_test);

    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
    findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_test);
    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager); 

    final CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mainActivity.this, answerFirst,answerSecond);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `getApplicationContext()`? Don’t use that, there’s a difference between the types of `Contexts`. Using the application context could cause a memory leak because the application context will stay around longer that anything else and could possibly make your `Activity` unable to be destroyed, thus causing memory issues.

Comment: @Sakiboy thank you for your advice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that by making the adaptor class inside the main class and in the listener method of checkbox scroll to the required position as the RecyclerView is a global variable you can access it and scroll to required position.

```
rv.scrollToPosition(youPositionInTheAdapter)
```

else pass the instance of RecyclerView in the constructor and do the same

and to get the current item position inside the adaptor by `getAdapterPosition()`

or you can do it with layout manager like this

```
rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(youPositionInTheAdapter)
```